# Why my regular expression don 't return correct answer?

Tags: mysql, sql, function

I was trying to write sql function which returns me "correct " when are the only number but returns me always false.

```
enter drop function if exists findByPesel;

delimiter $$

create function findByPesel(pesel varchar(11) ) returns varchar(255) deterministic 

begin 
    declare message varchar(255) default 'nothing'; 
    declare peselid varchar(12);
    declare findByPesel varchar(12);



if pesel  like '%[0-9]%' then
  set message ='correct';
  else
  set  message  ='Not correct pesel. Write a pesel consisting of digits greater than zero';
  end if;
  return message;
  end $$

  delimiter ;

  select findByPesel('3') as result;
```

result 'Not correct pesel. Write a pesel consisting of digits greater than zero'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL only supports the ANSI standard wildcards in `LIKE` -- `%` and `_`.

You want a regular expression, specifically:

```
if pesel regexp '[0-9]' then
```

Regular expressions match anywhere in the string, so the wildcards are not needed, only the character range.

Comment: Work !! Thank you Gordon